# On iPhone, can I tell if group text messages were delivered?

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

The question is in the subject.  Iphone 6 plus - ios 8.  I know I can tell for individuals, but not for groups - or at least not obviously.

Can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. The reason being is that it saying delivered would have to guarantee that it was delivered/read by each phone and one message would not be able to do that. Maybe Apple will add a more robust system in the future though.

Comment: I figured.  Just seems like a dumb thing not to have implemented some way.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, there are no delivery or read receipts for group messages (regardless of the size). Even when all participants are using iMessage, it will not display either receipt.

---

Note: Whatsapp does provide for this. Tap and hold a message. Tap "info". At the bottom, it will show who read the message.